# HTML and PHP Query

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<tr>
<td class="mHeads" rowspan="4" > GENERAL </td>
<th class="subHeads"> 2G Network </th>
<td class = "currentSel"><?php echo $row["2GNetwork"];
</td>
</tr>




.currentSel {
width:230px;
border:1px solid black;
max-width:230px;
height: 35px;
}
```

In the above code, the echo statement is overflowing the data rather than adding increasing the length of the row. Can anyone help me how to fix it without using the overflow property?

Comment: why you do not increase the height or the width of the cell in css ?

Comment: I needed word wrap actually! And the problem is solved. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.currentSel {
  width:230px;
  border:1px solid black;
  max-width:230px;
  height: 35px;
      overflow-y: auto
}
```

Already you have used width and height so, there is no way to get the extra space, only thing you can do is add `overflow-y: auto` or remove width or height.

Comment: I commented the height part and i do need to fix the width in order to make it stay in a specific div and to split the screen. But the data overflows and i don't want to put scroll in the data. Isn't there anyway that the height increases automatically with the amount of data in "td" tag?

Comment: You could use word-wrap on your cell for that
<td style="word-wrap:break-word"></td> and if you want it to stay in the cell you should set <table style="table-layout: fixed">